# Xamarin.Android HttpClient Image Download SIGSEGV 11

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using this code to download images from a server with a specific url:

```
double tmpProcessed = await Task.Run<double>(async () => {
            if (vues.Count > 0) {
                foreach (Vue v in vues) {
                    processed++;
                    updateProgress((processed * 100 / total));

                    string filename = v.gallery__file.Replace("./", "");

                    // Download File

                    try {
                        string path = Path.Combine(vueDirectory.AbsolutePath, filename);
                        //Save the Image using writeAsync
                        FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                        {
                            byte[] buffer = await client.GetByteArrayAsync("http://XXXX/site_media/" + filename);
                            await fs.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);          
                        }


                        //Close file connection
                        fs.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)  {
                        Log.Error("XXXX", ex.ToString());
                    }
                    finally {
                        App.db.SaveVues(v);
                    }
                }
            }
            return processed;
        });
```

I tested my app on many android device and it works very well. But now i test it on a old tablet (Panasonic running android 4.0.3). So it download some image using HttpClient but randomly after a moment i got a SIGSEGV 11. I'm 100% sure it comes from the download part because when i bypass this part all works very well.

In logs i can see informations like:

- suspend_thread suspend took 200 ms, which is more than the allowed
  200 ms
- Could not unwind with `libunwind.so`: Cannot load library
- Cannot load library: load_library[1091]: Library '/data/data/RescueCode.Droid.RescueCode.Droid/lib/libcorkscrew.so' not found
- Time Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
  10-11 22:06:23.039  PANASONIC FZ-A1B    Error   7898    libc    Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1)

Did someone met this kind of error. Tried to find informations on the web but seems to be a rare error.

Thanks everybody !

Comment: Removed the file saving part, still error, removed the downloading part + saving part : no error. I tried 4 - 5 times like this but got the error again. Looks like it comes from the Task part ?

Answer (score 0):

When i run the application without any usb connector it works very well .. seems to be linked to Xamarin with debug mode ?